# How to do this conditional compilation 'elegantly'?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have a code that needs to run fast and I am optimizing the heck out of the inner loop that is run several hundred trillion times.

In pursuit of this, I have been writing several different versions of the code in this inner loop, some using naive methods, some using SSE intrinsics, etc etc. I did all of this with the idea that when I run it it on a particular hardware combination I could run a test, see which implementation / compiler commands combination worked best and run it.

At first when it was only two different methods I used a simple conditional compilation inside the loop as follows

```
do
{
    #ifdef naive_loop
    //more code here
    #endif
    #ifdef partially_unrolled_loop
    //more code here
    #endif
}
while( runNumber < maxRun );
```

Later as the number of variations and different things I tried grew, it turned into this:

```
#ifdef naive_loop
void CalcRunner::loopFunction()
{
//code goes here
}
#endif
#ifdef partially_unrolled_loop
void CalcRunner::loopFunction()
{
//code goes here
}
#endif
#ifdef sse_intrinsics
void CalcRunner::loopFunction()
{
//code goes here
}
#endif
//etc
```

However this is making my file become enormous and annoying to read.
Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: is it an requirement that the it should be conditionally selected using macros?

Comment: Multiple source files, once per implementation, might be a better call (if that doesn't add significant code redundancy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use template and template specialization to do the job. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class CalcRunner;

template <>
class CalcRunner<naive_loop>
{
   void loopFunction(void){...}
};

template <>
class CalcRunner<partially_unrolled_loop>
{
   void loopFunction(void){...}
};

// Now instantiate what you wanna at compiler time

typename CalcRunner<partially_unrolled_loop> CalcRunner_t

int main()
{
   CalcRunner_t runner;
   runner.loopFunction();
}
```

Comment: Oooooh, I had forgotten about the template system... I guess I have not been using it enough lately.

Comment: I forget can template specialization be done with a single member function instead of the whole class? I ask because there are several functions that set up the calculation or send results to a lock-free queue to be retrieved by another thread and written out to disk.

Comment: @JamesMatta You can do template specialization with single functions. But there are some differences between class template specialization and function template specializatoin. Among one of them is that you can only do full template specialization with functions

Comment: All right, I will have to read up on the topic then. Template specialization is one of those things that I know it exists and know it is used in some parts of the std libraries, but I don't know much about in and of itself since I almost never need to write template code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put the different implementations in different files, and conditionally include the proper one?
That's what people usually do for multiplatform code.

Comment: I had been leaning towards this in my head but I was hesitant to do it because I seem to remember that it is a Bad Thing to use #include like that, though that might be some ancient remnant of long ago classes in my head.